# How to align C++ class member names in one column in emacs?

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation, code-formatting

I would like to align all C++ class member **names** ( do not confuse with member types ) in one column.

Lets look at the example of what we have at entrance:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void   method1( );
    int                  method2( ); 
    const Bar *        method3( ) const; 
protected:
    float    m_member;
};
```

and this is what we would like to have at the end:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void           method1( );
    int            method2( ); 
    const Bar *    method3( ) const; 
protected:
    float          m_member;
};
```

So the longest member type declaration defines the column to which class member names will be aligned.
How can i perform such transformation in emacs ?

Comment: You could use `align-regexp` with some funky stuff to sort of achieve the effect but I agree with Neil.

Comment: What happens when Jimmy on your team adds a new method that returns a `const Thingummyjiggle*`? Should he edit every other line in your header file?

Comment: Neil: It is hard to discuss about one's preferences :) I personally think that this form of class memeber formatting is nice and elegant. It also helps to you to read member methods faster without straining your eye muscles too much.

Comment: Noufal: Thx for the tip. I will check that out.

Comment: Johnsyweb: Basicly yes, whole file or at least part of it ( public section, group of similar methods ) should be parsed to meet the formatting standard. What I want is to be able to select some part of the class and format it according to above description.

Comment: Surprisingly unhelpful comment, Neil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the region with the method declarations

```
M-x align-regexp
```

Enter the string `[^ ]+\((\|;\)`  and press Enter

*Edited* to add the `;` in the matching, which aligns the member variable as well.

Comment: I added the semicolon which aligns the member variable as well.

Comment: and @Tray, your merged solution solves the posted problem. Thank you both :)